# Ensure thread-safety of static boolean check

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

A pattern that occurs several times in my code is a function that requires a certain initialization function to be called, which is currently solved as follows

```
void doSomething(){
    static bool _isInitialized = false;
    if( ! _isInitialized ){
        initializationFunction();
        _isInitialized = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

This kind of function is however not thread-safe as far as I understand since it can occur that one thread is executing `initializationFunction` and another thread starts doing the same before `_isInitialized` is set to true.

I am new to writing multithreaded code, and am wondering what would be a good way to make such code thread-safe. One possible solution seems to be to put a lock around this code, but I would rather avoid using locks. Is there another (better) way to solve this?

Comment: For this use-case perhaps [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) could be useful.

Comment: As of `c++11` you could simply have `static bool _isInitialized = initializationFunction()` -- assuming `initializationFunction` returns a `bool`.

Comment: std::call_once seems like exactly what I need. Thanks, I was not aware of its existence. The problem with returning a boolean from `initializationFunction` is that in many cases I am not the author of said function, since it comes from another package.

Comment: If `initializationFunction` doesn't return a `bool` itself you can still wrap it in a `lambda` that *does* return a `bool`.  Your choice though.

Comment: That's indeed a good point I did not consider. Though in this case std::call_once seems to be slightly shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by 'Some programmer dude', a possible solution is to use std::call_once. The code could then be rewritten as:

```
void doSomething(){
    static std::once_flag flag;
    std::call_once( initializationFunction, flag );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the signature of `initializationFunction` is up to some third party (as suggested in the comments) then you can do something like...

```
void doSomething ()
{
    static bool _isInitialized =
        []()
        {
            initializationFunction();
            return true;
        }();
}
```